# What is "IdlingResourceTimeoutException" in Espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I recently using espresso to do test with my android app. But sometimes the test case passed, sometimes not. It is a very long async task takes about 30 second to finish it. When it failed, it throws me this exception:

IdlingResourceTimeoutException

So does anyone know why this happens and what is the meaning of this exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That must be that the asynctask takes too much time to execute.

Try changing this idling timeout using:

```
IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this works. Since I set these params, this problem never happen again.